# How to show current search when filtering using dynamic parameters

Tags: search, dynamic, filter, parameters

I'm looking to create a filtering system for entries. I need to be able to filter by multiple criteria.

I've started to use the dynamic parameters feature, using the 'search' parameter to filter using custom fields.

**My question is this:** How can I show what current search terms are being used? As the URL doesn't change it doesn't appear we can use that, but I need to be able to show what filters are currently being applied.

Any ideas on this will be gratefully received, or any alternative methods or add-ons that will make this kind of filtering of entries easy.

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: An alternative would be [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search) or [Solspace Super Search](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/super_search/)

Answer (score 1):

I do this using great addon from Rob Sanchez http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dynamo (going to use default EE search, but dynamic parameters are not passed when using pagination).

not sure if you are ok with submitting the form with your inputs, but you can show (even select) your filter criteria..

Let us know